# How can I open a matlab using VBA statements

Tags: matlab, vba

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim MatLab As Object
    Set MatLab = CreateObject("Matlab.Application")
    MatLab.Execute ("a = 1")
    MatLab.Execute ("disp(a)")

End Sub
```

I need to display the value of Variable "a" in matlab and Display window should be visible to me, to check whether the commands are Executed or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to write the code in MATLAB and just use VBA as a shell to execute that function.

In VBA, you can use `shell` like this.

```
shell "C:\Matlab2011a\matlab.exe -r your_function_name
```

and in your Matlab code

```
function yourFunction()
  cd('C:\yourDirectory');  % moves you to your desired directory
                           % your code here
  exit;                    % exits Matlab
end
```

Second method:

You can use [SpreadSheet Link EX](http://www.mathworks.com/help/exlink/getting-started-with-spreadsheet-link-ex.html) and the function called [matlabinit](http://www.mathworks.com/help/exlink/matlabinit.html).